# Can i use 1/0 THHN/THWN-2 Building Wire

Tags: electrical, power-supply

Would this be ok to use from the house to a outdoor garage for the main power line?  House has 200 fuse box. Shop will have the same but just your standard plus stuff being used with lights etc

Comment: Don't waste money on copper wire. At those large sizes, aluminum feeder has always been reliable, and is 1/4 the price.

Comment: Power line for _what_? Do you actually have fuses? Please revise to add more information. Also take the [tour] so you know how to use this site. "Thanks" comments are discouraged.

Comment: when you don't give us any details, we can't give you any help.  This stuff is complicated to use. You really ought to sell it on Craigslist and buy on Craigslist the right stuff for your job.

Comment: Deleting the contents of your post to replace it with "Thanks" does nobody any good - how is someone supposed to find this again in the future and learn from it if you've deleted the question? Please take the [tour] to see how this place works. The appropriate way to say thanks is to click the up arrow next to every answer that you found helpful and the check mark next to the one you found _most_ helpful. It's up to you to decide what "most helpful" is to you.

Answer (score 4):

If you install conduit for it to run in, correctly (depth of burial depends on type of conduit and whether it's driven over or not, among other things) and you are content with 120 amps (or less) to the Garage (breaker size feeding it at the house end - garage panel can be 200 Amps) sure.

Unless of course you were planning to waste far more money than makes any sense on copper 1/0, in which case 150 amps, but at a huge waste of money .vs. using 4/0 aluminum and larger conduit to run up to 180 amps - either of which seems dubious with a 200 amp main at the house that feeds it.

Depending what your "standard stuff" is, there might be less expensive ways to get it done at only slightly lower amperage, i.e. #2 (2-2-2-4) aluminum "mobile home feeder" which can do 90 amps and tends to be attractively priced. That can be direct buried (24" soil above, minimum) or run in conduit the whole way. The parts inside the buildings need to be in conduit, at least.

In comments you have clarified that you have access to free wire, and minimal planned loads at present. The oversized wire will be good to have in case you or a future buyer of your house ever wants to put an electric vehicle charger or more of a shop in the garage, for instance.

The wire MUST be in conduit - it is not rated to be used exposed, either interior or outside/buried. Free wire should make buying the conduit to put it in fairly affordable. You will need, for instance, 2" schedule 80 PVC to run the **four** 1/0 THWN-2 wires in. That needs to be buried with 18" (or more) of soil over the **top** of the conduit. Get some "Buried Electrical Line Below" marking tape as well, and put it in the top part of the trench when refilling. The conduit *must* be completely assembled and backfilled before pulling the wires in.

You *need* four conductors. Hot, Hot, Neutral, and Ground. If buying wire you would use a smaller size for ground, but if you have free wire available, might as well use that. You cannot (since 40-50 years ago) run only 3 wires for a subpanel.

Comment: I am looking for to run the garage lights, and just your standard 110 drill etc.  Nothing big.  The reason why I am thinking of this is this wire I can get for free.    It would be buried in the yard, so the only thing driving over it would be a lawn mower.

Comment: @Steve the wrong thing for free should not be used, except for trade bait.  What you need is less, so the trade should definitely be in your favor.  You could find yourself with the right wires *and* cash in pocket!

Answer (score 3):

If this is copper wire, it's worth a king's ransom. Trade it for a more appropriate wire! Use of copper for such a large feeder is wasteful and foolish, *even if it's free!* Wasteful fools are rich, so take their money, buy what you need and a really nice subpanel too, and a couple of pizzas.  Win/win/win.

If it's aluminum, it's the right stuff for feeder, but way, way too large for your nee--

-- *wait.  This just in.  Home buyers are paying thousands more for houses that are wired up and ready to go for electric vehicle charging.  Needs are 240V@30A for a basic basic light charger, and 240V@80A for deluxe multiple-vehicle charging using Share2 technology*.

Well, there you go.  That stuff is good for 115 amps, so it'll run everything you'll ever need, with headroom for a wood shop, hot tub, pool, 100A of EV charging, whatever you might want.

Get a nice big subpanel (24 space minimum, preferably 30, not circuits, spaces!) because that much power can run a whole bunch of stuff. And 240V loads munch spaces 2 at a time.